# How can you tell whether to delete a pointer returned from a function or not

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Consider a function that returns a `Type*`, and so it looks like it could allocate a `Type` in its definition, but you can't tell for sure (there are many functions, and you don't have the time to read their definitions).

How can you tell if you should delete the pointer returned or not? for example, this is the type:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    MyStruct(void) { cout << "Created.\n"; }
    ~MyStruct(void) { cout << "Deleted.\n"; }
};
```

And this is the function:

```
MyStruct* Func1(void)
{
    return (new MyStruct());
}
```

Func1 allocated a pointer, and you should later de-allocate it. but maybe the definition is something else, and the pointer shouldn't be `delete`d.

My question is: How can you tell if to delete the pointer or not? for example: maybe the pointer is static?

```
MyStruct* Func2(void)
{
    static MyStruct* ms = &MyStruct();
    return ms;
}
```

De-allocating this pointer would crash the entire program.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can you tell if you should delete the pointer returned or not?

You can't, and that is one reason why it's a very bad idea to use raw pointers to manage memory. If an object needs deleting, then that should always be done automatically, using a smart pointer.

This also has the advantage that the dynamic object will always be deleted once you've finished with it, even if an exception gets thrown.

```
std::unique_ptr<MyStruct> Func1()
{
    return std::unique_ptr<MyStruct>(new MyStruct);
}

void do_something()
{
    auto thing = Func1();
    do_something_with(thing);

    // The object is automatically deleted here
    // even if the function threw an exception.
}
```

If you're forced to use a badly-designed library with functions return pointers that might or might not need deleting, then your only choice is to either read the documentation or find a better library. It would be a good idea to immediately assign any pointer that needs deleting to a smart pointer, so you at least have exception safety.

Comment: Disagree with "in any case" - assigning a pointer-to-static to a smart pointer would not be wise...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Yes, I was a bit unclear; I only meant for the case of a dynamic object.

Answer (score 8):

There is no way of checking this programmatically.<sup>1</sup>  You, as the programmer, need to be aware of what needs deleting and what doesn't.

More generally, this is one reason by passing raw pointers around in C++ is often frowned-upon.  [*Smart pointers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) are often used to manage dynamically-allocated memory.

---

<sub>1. At least, not in a robust platform-independent way.</sub>

Comment: Exactly. The OP's "you don't have the time to read their definitions" is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Fact: If you don't have the time to read the docs on an API, then you are going to have bugs.

It comes down to the principle that **functions always make lots of assumptions**, all enforced by different mechanisms:

1. Some are enforced **automatically by the compiler**, usually via types. For example if the function must assume it can write to a certain argument, its type will be non-const, and passing a const argument will cause a compiler error. This is the best way to prevent bugs. Returning a smart pointer is a way to provide compiler enforcement for pointer ownership, so that documentation is not needed. This is why we prefer templates or base classes over `void*`.
2. Some are implied through **common practice or convention**. Again this means you don't need to read the documentation to comply with the function's assumptions, because it should be obvious to any competent programmer. For example if a C++ function asks for a row or column of a grid, you can expect it to be 0-based. This is convention. Or for your case, if the function returns a *reference* it would imply by convention that the caller should not delete the object.
3. Still many assumptions cannot be enforced at all except through **documentation**. For example you cannot know if the function will do bounds checking or accept a NULL pointer. As an API developer you should avoid this if you can, but when facing it, you cannot ignore the documentation.

As C++ developers we try as hard as possible to use #1 as much as possible, but the others cannot be avoided entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I agree completely with Mike and Oli, with just one addition: If the library is well written, then there's probably some standard used to point out when exactly you are the owner of the pointer return by a function (meaning you have to delete it). This could be done either by naming, or the function belongs to a certain class/namespace. In that case, you can avoid reading the functions' definitions for each one.